# Economics PhD graduate?

Tags: academic-graduate, government, soft-question, research

What are the options for Economics PhD students after graduation? I am aware most students end up going into academia as either professors or researchers. What are the options in the corporate world for an Economics PhD graduate?

Comment: This is probably more on-topic at Academia.SE. At any rate, take a look at the job postings at American Economic Association's website for an idea: https://www.aeaweb.org/joe/listings

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about economics.

Answer (score 3):

Your claim that most go into academia is wrong. From the top universities, about half to two-thirds go into academia, but from most universities, most go to non-academic careers. It's simple accounting: a top-30 university graduates about 20 PhDs in economics per year, hires 1 or 2.

Google "[university name] economics job market outcomes", or "[university name] economics placement" to see where the PhDs get jobs.

Corporate world: economic consulting, management consulting, banking, large companies like Amazon, Wal-Mart, Uber.

Answer (score 0):

Sander's answer about checking various Economics PhD program websites for their recent placements is good advice.

Also, the American Economic Association has a list of Job Openings for Economists on their website (https://www.aeaweb.org/joe/listings). This may help give you an idea as to where recent graduates with Economics PhDs will end up.